# Center a submit button on a form CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to align the submit button on this form to the center at the bottom but when trying to do so it only wants to move in relation to the `<body>` element as opposed to the `<form>` element,

I'd like to avoid having to go through positioning it step-by-step i.e. `left: Xpx; top: Ypx;`. Feel free to completely shred apart my CSS & HTML - I'm a beginner at best so I'm still figuring out best practice etc. I know I'm probably missing something so incredibly silly :')

I've edited all the actual class names etc. just because I cringe at sharing my actual work lol

```css
.main-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #C9D1C8;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: italic;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #5B7065;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 65vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px;
  color: #04202C;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 88%;
  margin-left: 28px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #C9D1C8;
  color: #304040;
  font-style: italic;
}

button {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #04202C;
  color: #C9D1C8;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.footer-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-flex-container">
  <h1 id="page-title">Survey Form</h1>

  <p id="page-description">Brief description</p>

  <form method="POST" id="whole-form">
    <div>
      <label for="question-1">Question 1</label>
      <input id="question-1" name="question-1-box" type="text" placeholder="Question 1">
      </input>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="question-2">Question 2</label>
      <input id="question-2" name="question-2-box" type="text" placeholder="question 2">
      </input>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="question-3">Question 3</label>
      <input id="question-3" name="question-3-box" type="text" placeholder="question 3" required>
      </input>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="question-4">Question 4</label>
      <input id="question-4" name="question-4-box" type="text" placeholder="question 4" required>
      </input>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</main>
<footer class="footer-flex-container">Last updated: 2/05/2023</footer>
```

Comment: "*I've edited all the actual class names etc. just because I cringe at sharing my actual work*" - while trimming your work down to the smallest amount necessary to demonstrate your problem is required, don't be ashamed of not being perfect: everybody has to start learning somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you simply add `margin: auto;` to the div? Or are you referring to another type of centering? Looks like that's what you want :D

```css
/* MODIFIED */

.submitWrapper {
  margin: auto;
}


/* MODIFIED END */

.main-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #C9D1C8;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: italic;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #5B7065;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 65vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px;
  color: #04202C;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 88%;
  margin-left: 28px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #C9D1C8;
  color: #304040;
  font-style: italic;
}

button {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #04202C;
  color: #C9D1C8;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.footer-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-flex-container">
  <h1 id="page-title">Survey Form</h1>

  <p id="page-description">Brief description</p>

  <form method="POST" id="whole-form">
    <div>
      <label for="question-1">Question 1</label>
      <input id="question-1" name="question-1-box" type="text" placeholder="Question 1">
      </input>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="question-2">Question 2</label>
      <input id="question-2" name="question-2-box" type="text" placeholder="question 2">
      </input>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="question-3">Question 3</label>
      <input id="question-3" name="question-3-box" type="text" placeholder="question 3" required>
      </input>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="question-4">Question 4</label>
      <input id="question-4" name="question-4-box" type="text" placeholder="question 4" required>
      </input>
    </div>

    <div class="submitWrapper">
      <!-- MODIFIED -->

      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</main>
<footer class="footer-flex-container">Last updated: 2/05/2023</footer>
```